# how to view the details of a formations already added

Tags: node.js, angular

***i used angular2, when i go to view the details of a formation already added nothing is display***
**i did show.ts and show.html to retrieve information from a formation**
*I tried several times but did not find a solution*
*please someone can help me*

**this is my show.ts**

```
export class ShowComponent implements OnInit {

  formation: Observable<Formation>;

  constructor( 

    public formationService:FormationService,
    public route:ActivatedRoute,
    public router:Router
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.getFormation();

  }


getFormation(){
  this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
  this.formation = this.formationService.getFormation(params['id']); 
  });

}
```

**this is my show.html**

```
    <div class="container"> 
        <div class="row">
        <h2><strong> voir Detail </strong>  <br/></h2><br/>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" *ngIf="formation "  >
        <br>
        <br>
          <form >
            <div class="form-group">
             <b> <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Title</label></b>
              <p type="text" class="form-control">{{ formation.title }}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
             <b><label for="exampleInputPassword1">Url</label></b> 
              <p type="text" class="form-control">{{ formation.url }}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <b><label for="exampleInputPassword1">description</label></b>
              <p type="text" class="form-control">{{ formation.description }}</p>
            </div>

            <a class="btn btn-info" >Cancel</a>   


          </form>
**this is my app.route**
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {path:'', component : HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
  {path:'register', component : RegisterComponent },
  {path:'login', component : LoginComponent },
  {path:'dashboard', component : DashboardComponent },
  {path:'profile', component :ProfileComponent},
  {path:'formations', component :FormationsComponent},
  {path:'contact', component :ContactComponent},
  {path:'admin', component :AdminComponent},
  {path:'candidat', component :CandidatComponent},
  {path:'formations-prop', component :FormationsPropComponent},
  {path:'add', component :AddComponent},
  {path:'navbar1', component :Navbar1Component},
  {path:'edit', component :EditComponent},
  {path:'home1', component :Home1Component},
  {path:'show/:id', component :ShowComponent},
  {path:'nosformations', component :NosformationsComponent}


  ]
```

[captur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FjWQn.png)

Comment: Check how Angular works, an Angular component has a template and a class, both are connected to each other in the component code

Comment: Open a console and show what kind of error you have.

Comment: @Kraken nothing is displayed in the consol, it is empty

Comment: can you add FormationService

Comment: Try to change your template interpolation snippets to this `{{formation?.description}}` and check that you added this template `show.html` to your component decorator

Comment: import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'; 


@Injectable()
export class FormationService {

  constructor(private http:Http) { }
addFormation(info){
    return this.http.post("http://localhost:3001/formations",info)
        .map(res => res.json());
  }
  
  getFormation(id){
    return this.http.get("http://localhost:3001/formations" +id)
        .map(res => res.json());
  }  
@Robert

Comment: @Kraken I added the question mark in show.html but nothing is changed

Comment: @khouloud can you check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like formationService returns observable.

Instead of

```
this.formation = this.formationService.getFormation(params['id']);
```

just subscribe to observable

```
this.formationService.getFormation(params['id'])
                     .subscribe(formation => this.formation = formation);
```

Comment: it not works 
that's the mistake I've made
zone.js:2019 GET http://localhost:3001/formations5b616cffd0bc9e10b0c461e2 404 (Not Found)

Comment: change return  return this.http.get("localhost:3001/formations"; +id)  to  return  this.http.get("localhost:3001/formations/"; +id)

Answer (score 0):

Asper your service you need get like that

```
getFormation(){
  this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
  this.formationService.getFormation(params['id']).subscribe(
            response => {
                     this.formation = response;
            },
            error => {
             console.log(error)
            }); 
  });

}
```

Comment: it not works , 
that's the mistake I've made
zone.js:2019 GET http://localhost:3001/formations5b616cffd0bc9e10b0c461e2 404 (Not Found

Comment: But you need call service like what we mentioned above

Comment: I replaced the get formation function with the one you gave me but still nothing displayed

Comment: @khouloud can you console.log(response)